# setting your own font in asset for whole android applicatin

Tags: android

I just want change font for my whole application. i just want to have 3 kind of fonts in my asset and when user click my setting it change whole font.
I found some example but i cant understand the way . 
I just new with android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library looks quite nice but if you don't know pretty well how use it or you think is too difficult use it you can follow next steps:

In your project, create a folder called "**assets**" in the same level than res, src, etc...

Inside of this folder create another folder called "**fonts**" and copy in it the fonts that you need to use...in my case... Robot-Regular.ttf

I think the most used kind of file is ***.ttf**

Ok, I am not sure if you know create one class which extend from the class **Application** (if not, check it in internet because it is really important).

In your **Application class** of your project include:

```
private static Typeface primaryFont;

/**
 * @return primary font Typeface
 * 
 * By keeping only one instance of the typeface, the app performance is increased massively!
 */
public static Typeface getPrimaryFontTypeface() {
    if(primaryFont == null){
        primaryFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(CameraManager.getContext().getAssets(), Constants.PRIMARY_FONT_PATH);
    }

    return primaryFont;
}
```

After in whatever place where you want to use this custom font you will need to set the typeface, by example, to one TextView:

```
TextView email = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.email_tv);
email.setTypeface(getApp().getPrimaryFontTypeface());
```

If you don't want to write these lines of code everytime that you want to use this custom font, you will need to create a CustomTextView. To create a custom view where you can modify the normal behaviour of that view, you will need to create another question on stackoverflow.

Hope to be helpful. If it is, please score my answer. Thanks! ;)

Comment: If you take the decision about go for the custom view. you could ask me it but in another question in stackoverflow...thanks by the way!

Comment: of course yes I ask it . but is there any sample to dl ?

Comment: I cant ask any more question :-(((((((((

Comment: Can you score my answer?

Comment: I really like to ask but I have reached my question limit ...:-( maybe to daye later

Comment: is there any way to chat with you?

Comment: yes, it is...i can publish a comment in stackoverflow with my email during some minutes...after i will delete de comment...let me know when you are online

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library, the most easy way to change the fonts in android.

Comment: but it seems difficult

Comment: It's harder to do it by yourself. You have to setup all views, one by one. 
However, with Calligraphy  you can do it directly in XML declaration

Comment: @mhs can you let me know why it seems difficult? I want to make sure the out of the box solution is really easy.